# Unicode in Content-Disposition header

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, content-disposition

I am using HttpContext object implemented in HttpHandler child to download a file, when I have non-ascii characters in file name it looks weird in IE whereas it looks fine in Firefox.

below is the code:-

```
       context.Response.ContentType = ".cs";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}",filename));
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

context.Response.Flush();
```

when I supply 'ÃŸ' 'Ã¤' 'Ã¶' 'Ã¼' 'Ã³' 'ÃŸ' 'Ã¤' 'Ã¶' 'Ã¼' 'Ã³' in file name field it looks different than what I have in file name it looks fine in firefox. adding EncodingType and charset has been of no use.

In ie it is 'ÃƒÅ¸'*'ÃƒÂ¤'*'ÃƒÂ¶'*'ÃƒÂ¼'*'ÃƒÂ³'*'ÃƒÅ¸'*'ÃƒÂ¤'*'ÃƒÂ¶'*'ÃƒÂ¼'_'ÃƒÂ³' and in firefox it is 'ÃŸ' 'Ã¤' 'Ã¶' 'Ã¼' 'Ã³' 'ÃŸ' 'Ã¤' 'Ã¶' 'Ã¼' 'Ã³'.

Any Idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Is this the content of the file, or the filename itself?

Comment: @leppie, it is filename itself

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had similar problem. You have to use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) or [Server.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738.aspx) to encode filename. Also I remember firefox didn't need it. Moreoverit ruined filename when it's url-encoded. My code:

```
// IE needs url encoding, FF doesn't support it, Google Chrome doesn't care
if (Request.Browser.IsBrowser ("IE"))
{
    fileName = Server.UrlEncode(fileName);
}

Response.Clear ();
Response.AddHeader ("content-disposition", String.Format ("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
Response.AddHeader ("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

**Edit**

I have read specification more carefully. First of all [RFC2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) states that:

> Current [RFC 2045] grammar restricts parameter values (and hence Content-Disposition filenames) to US-ASCII.

But then I found references that [RFC 2045] is absolete and one must reference [RFC 2231](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2231.html), which states:

> Asterisks ("*") are reused to provide
> the indicator that language and
> character set information is present
> and encoding is being used. A single
> quote ("'") is used to delimit the
> character set and language information
> at the beginning of the parameter
> value. Percent signs ("%") are used as
> the encoding flag, which agrees with
> RFC 2047.

Which means that you can use UrlEncode for non-ascii symbols, as long as you include the encoding as stated in the [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987).  Here is an example:

```
string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"; filename*=UTF-8''{0}", Server.UrlEncode(fileName, Encoding.UTF8));
```

Note that `filename` is included in addition to `filename*` for backwards compatibility. You can also choose another encoding and modify the parameter accordingly, but UTF-8 covers everything.

Comment: @Sergej, I tried what you said and it works fine, can you please explain why it ruined  filename, so that I have it clear in my mind before I actually implement it.

Comment: As per Ash's answer, I used this but with `UrlPathEncode`, which worked like a charm (it doesn't add the '+' signs).

Comment: Thanks for this. I am using Java and used Guava's PercentageEncoder to encode the filename:  `new PercentEscaper("_-", false).escape(filename)`

Comment: Been using Firefox 46, the only problem for me was single quotes `''`  after `filename*=`. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode might be a better option. As URLEncode will replace spaces with '+' signs.

Answer (score 5):

For me this solution is working on all major browsers:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename*=UTF-8''{0}", HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName).Replace(",", "%2C"));
var mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
return File(fileName, mime);
```

Using ASP.NET MVC 3.

The Replace is necessary, because Chrome doesn't like Comma (,) in parameter values: http://www.gangarasa.com/lets-Do-GoodCode/tag/err_response_headers_multiple_content_disposition/

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read [RFC 6266](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html) and look at the tests at http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/.

Answer (score 2):

For me this solved the problem:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   Content = new ByteArrayContent(data)
};

result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileNameStar = "foo-ä-€.html"
};
```

When i look ad the repsonse in fiddler i can see the filename has automaticcaly been encoded using UTF-8:

[Fiddler response example with encoded Content-Disposition filename using UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R8eb.png)

If we look at the value of the Content-Disposition header we can see it will be the same as @Johannes Geyer his answer. The only difference is that we didn't have to do the encoding ourselfs, the ContentDispositionHeaderValue class takes care of that.

I used the Testcases for the Content-Disposition header on: http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/ as mentioned by Julian Reschke.
Information about the ContentDispositionHeaderValue class can be found on MSDN.

Comment: I encoded value for FileNameStar. It did not work. The framework already handles encoding nicely.

Answer (score 0):

For Asp.Net Core (version 2 as of this post) UrlPathEncode is deprecated, here's how to achieve the desired result:

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
   FileName = Uri.EscapeUriString(fileName),
   Inline = true  // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline
};

Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I`m using `Uri.EscapeUriString` for converts all characters to their hexadecimal representation, and `string.Normalize` for Unicode normalization form C.
(tested in ASP.NET MVC5 framework 4.5)

```cs
    var contentDispositionHeader = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = false,
        FileName = Uri.EscapeUriString(Path.GetFileName(pathFile)).Normalize()
    };
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDispositionHeader.ToString());
    string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Server.MapPath(pathFile));
    return File(file, mimeType);
```