# Unicode characters lost in http response

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode, httpresponse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non Unicode in Content-Disposition header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543584/non-unicode-in-content-disposition-header)

My web application allow users to download a files, the code below is used. Some file names has Unicode character and these characters are lost in file download process. For example if the web app send file name `наталья.docx` the web browser download dialog show file name like `Ð½Ð°ÑÐ°Ð»ÑÑ.docx`. How to solve this problem?

```
var outputFileName = path+ "наталья.docx";
context.Response.ContentType = WebHelper.GetMimeType(outputFileName);
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("{0}; filename={1}", "attachment", outputFileName));
context.Response.BinaryWrite(binaryData);
context.Response.Flush();
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: u can add header "accept-charset" and define type of encoding which u are using in there
"Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"

Comment: try context.Response.AddHeader("accept-charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");

Comment: @Tomas, have you checked out the question I linked to? The short answer is that you can't directly use encodings other than ASCII in the `Content-Disposition` header, and if you want to use characters outside that set, you should %-encode your filename and send a `filename*` parameter with the header.