# multilinguale file name issue convert to url encode in browser

Tags: php, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

When user try to download file in pure **ie8** , not compatibility mode which have multilingual character in name it shown "fileAttachment" name .

that time i using

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''".rawurlencode ($fileInfo['fileName']));
```

to fix that error i am using

```
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.rawurlencode($fileInfo['fileName']).'"');
```

but issue here is that all multilingual character convert into url encode form in all browser.

is there any solution regarding this?

Comment: Why are you url-encoding it in the header? I haven't tried this but I assume you can double-quote it with no encoding?

Comment: Hmmm Seems this requires some browser sniffing to work around. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2543744/156755)