# Azure blob DownloadToStream specify local file name

Tags: c#, pdf, blob, azure-storage

I'm downloading a pdf file from Azure blob storage and specify the local file name and extension.

It downloads fine to the downloads directory but with the name `Microsoft.WidowsAzure.Storage.Blob` file name and no extension.

I want to specify the file name not the directory which is fine.

```
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = blockBlob.Properties.ContentType.ToString();
    // Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + blobName.ToString());    
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + blockBlob.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", blockBlob.Properties.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `.ToString()` method for any class, unless overridden by that class, will print the fully qualified class name (as is happening in your case). Instead you need to use the blob's `.Name` property to get the key. Once you have the key, you can strip it down to just the filename part:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(blob.Name);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

For safety (in terms of bad characters in the filename) you might want to consider using `filename*=` as described in [RFC6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.3) with appropriate encoding:

```
string encodedFileName = Server.UrlEncode(Path.GetFileName(blob.Name), Encoding.UTF8);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + fileName);
```

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543584/unicode-in-content-disposition-header) for more on that.